# Probability of Extinction in microbial cell line

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, evolutionary-game-theory

Suppose a single cell microbe can replicate into two cells during replication event. The probability that a cell is still alive until this event is given by $x$. Suppose we start with one single cell microbe on a plate. What is the probability that these microbes will eventually go extinct on the plate? What is the average generation time (number of replication events) to reach extinction?

I thought this was a simple geometric distribution problem. But I got really stuck right now.

Comment: To be sure:
* The extinction probability of a given microbe is constant over time, and
* The replication events happen after a constant time after the previous replication event (either the cell's birth, or its last replication).
Is this correct?

Comment: that's correct!